# Get the data with key values

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
    $year = array(2015,2016);
    $no = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

    $dr = [];
    foreach ($year as $yr)
    {
        $ar = [];   
        foreach ($no as $ss)
        {
           $aer['value'] = [12];

        }

        array_push($dr,$ar);

   }
   //print_r($dr);
?>
```

My php code looks like this.. The output of the following code looks as below:

array([0]=>array([2015]=>array([0]=>array([value]=12)...

But I need the output in the following format.. How to get the output in the following format.

```
array(
 [2015]=>array
         (
           [0]=>array([value]=>12)
           [1]=>array([value]=>12)
            :
            :
           [11]=>array([value]=>12)

         )
   [2016]=>array
         (
           [0]=>array([value]=>12)
           [1]=>array([value]=>12)
            :
            :
           [11]=>array([value]=>12)

         )
     )
```

Comment: all the child value as 12????

Comment: You did not assign anything to the contents of `$year`, maybe that is a good place to start. The rest is functioning fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it easier: [Working Example](https://3v4l.org/KHWVr)

Loop through the year and for each year you need to loop again the number of month. And you need store the value of the `12` as you want in to the forst index as the first array and inner array the 12 number and all the number also contain the array of index `value` and value `12`.

```
$year = array(2015,2016);
$no = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

$dr = [];
foreach ($year as $yr){
    foreach($no as $ss){
        $dr[$yr][] = array("value" => 12);
    }
}
print_r($dr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `array_map` function:

```
$no_arr = array_map(function($v) { return ['value' => 12]; }, $no);
$result = array_map(function($v) use($no_arr){ return [$v => $no_arr]; }, $year);

print_r($result);
```